# Scanner not scanning UTF-8 characters correctly (java)

Tags: java

I am making a console program that scans names which often include Czech characters like ěščřžáíé. In eclipse, it worked flawlessly but when I exported it into a jar file and ran it in cmd the scanner replaced the Czech characters with characters like "ˇçź". When I print the characters with `System.out.print("ěščřžýá");` They show correctly.  I tried using `chcp` 65001 in the cmd to change the encoding to UTF-8 but that completely removed the Czech letters everywhere in the program. I also tried using `new Scanner(System.in, "UTF-8")` but that just replaced the letters with question marks. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by executing `chcp` in cmd which printed out `Active code page: 852`, and then putting the 852 next to `new Scanner(System.in)` like this: `new Scanner(System.in, "Cp852")`. Now it prints and scans the characters correctly!